# Gradient of a function defined on a surface

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis

Let $V:R^{3}\rightarrow R$ be a differential function. 
Let $$A= 
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 2 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 3 \\
        \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Now, restrict $V$ to the ellipsoid $\{x\in R^{3}: x^{T}Ax=1\}$. Compute the gradient of $V$ in the metric induced by $A$. What is the relation between the partial derivative $(\partial{V}/\partial{x},\partial{V}/\partial{y},\partial{V}/\partial{z})$ and the gradient?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ellipsoid 
$${x^2} + 2{y^2} + 3{z^2} = 1$$
may be given a parametrized form like so:
$$\psi (u,v) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {x(u,v)} \\ 
  {y(u,v)} \\ 
  {z(u,v)} 
\end{array}} \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\frac{1}{{\sqrt 1 }}\cos (u)\cos (v)} \\ 
  {\frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}\sin (u)\cos (v)} \\ 
  {\frac{1}{{\sqrt 3 }}\sin (v)} 
\end{array}} \right)$$
The partials for this are given by
$$\frac{{\partial \psi }}{{\partial u}} = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\frac{{ - 1}}{{\sqrt 1 }}\sin (u)\cos (v)} \\ 
  {\frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}\cos (u)\cos (v)} \\ 
  0 
\end{array}} \right),\frac{{\partial \psi }}{{\partial v}} = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\frac{{ - 1}}{{\sqrt 1 }}\cos (u)\sin (v)} \\ 
  {\frac{{ - 1}}{{\sqrt 2 }}\sin (u)\sin (v)} \\ 
  {\frac{1}{{\sqrt 3 }}\cos (v)} 
\end{array}} \right)$$
These two vectors are tangential to our ellipsoid.
Now, the function $V$ restricted to the ellipsoid means:
$$V(\psi (u,v)) = V(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))$$
Calculating the gradient for this restriction, we get:
$$\begin{gathered}
  dV = \nabla V \cdot (dx,dy,dz) \hfill \\
   = \frac{{\partial V}}{{\partial x}} \cdot (\frac{{\partial x}}{{\partial u}}du + \frac{{\partial x}}{{\partial v}}dv) + \frac{{\partial V}}{{\partial y}} \cdot (\frac{{\partial y}}{{\partial u}}du + \frac{{\partial y}}{{\partial v}}dv) + \frac{{\partial V}}{{\partial z}} \cdot (\frac{{\partial z}}{{\partial u}}du + \frac{{\partial z}}{{\partial v}}dv) \hfill \\
   = (\frac{{\partial V}}{{\partial x}}\frac{{\partial x}}{{\partial u}} + \frac{{\partial V}}{{\partial y}}\frac{{\partial y}}{{\partial u}} + \frac{{\partial V}}{{\partial z}}\frac{{\partial z}}{{\partial u}})du + (\frac{{\partial V}}{{\partial x}}\frac{{\partial x}}{{\partial v}} + \frac{{\partial V}}{{\partial y}}\frac{{\partial y}}{{\partial v}} + \frac{{\partial V}}{{\partial z}}\frac{{\partial z}}{{\partial v}})dv \hfill \\
   = \nabla V \cdot \frac{{\partial \psi }}{{\partial u}}du + \nabla V \cdot \frac{{\partial \psi }}{{\partial v}}dv = (\nabla V \cdot \frac{{\partial \psi }}{{\partial u}},\nabla V \cdot \frac{{\partial \psi }}{{\partial v}}) \cdot (du,dv) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$
That is:

$$\nabla (V \circ \psi )(u,v) = (\nabla V(\psi (u,v)) \cdot \frac{{\partial \psi }}{{\partial u}}(u,v),\nabla V(\psi (u,v)) \cdot \frac{{\partial \psi }}{{\partial v}}(u,v))$$

and therefore:

$$\nabla (V \circ \psi ) = \left( {\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\frac{{\partial V}}{{\partial x}}} \\ 
  {\frac{{\partial V}}{{\partial y}}} \\ 
  {\frac{{\partial V}}{{\partial z}}} 
\end{array}} \right) \cdot \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\frac{{ - 1}}{{\sqrt 1 }}\sin (u)\cos (v)} \\ 
  {\frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}\cos (u)\cos (v)} \\ 
  0 
\end{array}} \right),\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\frac{{\partial V}}{{\partial x}}} \\ 
  {\frac{{\partial V}}{{\partial y}}} \\ 
  {\frac{{\partial V}}{{\partial z}}} 
\end{array}} \right) \cdot \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\frac{{ - 1}}{{\sqrt 1 }}\cos (u)\sin (v)} \\ 
  {\frac{{ - 1}}{{\sqrt 2 }}\sin (u)\sin (v)} \\ 
  {\frac{1}{{\sqrt 3 }}\cos (v)} 
\end{array}} \right)} \right)$$
[image]